# How can I put a video into a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, web

Since yesterday, I tried to find out a solution to put a video into canvas, but it's a canvas which has a specific shape like this one : http://letsdunkit.com/so/rectangle.html

I saw a lot of tutorials who talked about "drawImage" but that's not what I want or perhaps I'm wrong and I didn't use it  correctly.

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "put a video into a canvas"? Do you want to put a still image from a `<video>` element into a canvas?

Comment: Also, the canvas you linked to is a perfectly normal rectangle; it just has a parallelogram shape drawn on it.

Comment: Yes, I just want to play a video into a canvas with a <video> element.

Comment: C’mon, please show at least a little bit of own research effort! http://www.google.com/search?q=html5+canvas+video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `drawImage` with a `<video>` element argument to draw the currently displayed frame of the video:

```
<video id="myvideo" src="..."></video>
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>

...

// in a <script>...
var myvideo = document.getElementById("myvideo");
var mycanvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");

myvideo.play();

// assuming video is loaded (otherwise it won't have any frames to be drawn yet)
mycanvas.getContet("2d").drawImage(myvideo);
```

If you play the video and make `drawImage` calls repeatedly, you can show a series of images from the video as it plays.

O'Reilly has a [complete tutorial](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2896-how-to-display-a-video-on-html5-canvas/) on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

The canvas context method `drawImage` can take a HTMLImageElement, HTMLVideoElement, or HTMLCanvasElement.

Here is how you would draw frames of a video onto a canvas:

```
var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

var myVideo = document.createElement('video');
// Video tags usually have more than one source. Not all browsers can play Ogg/Theora
myVideo.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Mockingbird_Spring.ogv";
myVideo.autoplay = true;
myVideo.loop = true;

setInterval(function(){
    ctx.drawImage(myVideo, 0, 0, 400, 400);
}, 60);
```

Live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/simonsarris/jF4TE/